# Cannot initialize a graphdb repo with a SHACL Sail

Tags: graphdb, shacl

1. Set up a current graphdb free (tried with 9.3.3 and 9.4.0)
2. create a new repository in the workbench that has SHACL validation enabled
3. export it to ttl
4. set it up as an init repository that graphdb imports upon startup
5. observe that graphdb startup fails with the message
   `Only graphdb repositories are supported`

This is biting us when trying to set up automated deployments with a prepared db. Any suggestions how to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a repo programmatically using a config.ttl template, as described at http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/configuring-a-repository.html#configure-a-repository-programmatically:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "config=@./config.ttl"
  "http://localhost:7200/rest/repositories"
```

But I don't know what prop names you should use. So I posted an issue (GDB-5031) to document the Turtle prop names of the 9 new params described in http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/shacl-validation.html#creating-and-configuring-a-shacl-repository and to include them in `/configs/templates/config.ttl`

Comment: On that note, is there a preferred way to file suspected graphdb bugs? I think I found one and posted it here https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-workbench/issues/242

Comment: @fkleedorfer, that is not the correct project, but having it in github allows me to easily ping relevant people (in this case, Jeen Broekstra). If it turns out to be a GraphDB bug, I'll post in our |Jira. In the future, you can write to support at ontotext